# Judge whether the current process is running when SMP is turned on

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I found that there is a function called `task_running` in the kernel, and its judgment logic is as follows

```c
static inline int task_current(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p)
{
    return rq->curr == p;
}

static inline int task_running(struct rq *rq, struct task_struct *p)
{
#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
    return p->on_cpu;
#else
    return task_current(rq, p);
#endif
}
```

Is there any difference between `rq->curr` and `p->on_cpu`? I think they both mean that the process is being scheduled by the current cpu. Why are separate judgments required under SMP?

Answer (score 0):

On a multiprocessor system (`CONFIG_SMP`) the scheduler usually needs to continuously acquire and releases the spinlocks `p->pi_lock` (for tasks i.e. `struct task_struct`) and `rq->lock` (for runqueues i.e. `struct rq`). Since lock contention is one of the main factors of slowdown in the case of multiprocessor systems, the `on_cpu` field of `task_struct` was added to avoid acquiring `rq->lock` to look at `rq->curr`.

On a uniprocessor system (no `CONFIG_SMP`), there is only one CPU with one runqeueue, and there is no need to acquire runqueue locks when checking the running task. Since the scheduler will not do any locking anyway, we can also avoid having the `on_cpu` field in `task_struct`, saving some memory and also dumping all the code that deals with it. In fact, if you take a look at the code for `struct task_struct`, you can see:

```c
struct task_struct {
    /* ... */
#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
    int             on_cpu;
    /* ... */
#endif
    /* ... */
}
```

Here's [the relevant commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=3ca7a440da394808571dad32d33d3bc0389982e6) that implemented this optimization. It was part of [this patchwork](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/cover/244310/) by Peter Zijlstra to reduce lock contention in the scheduler (expand the "related" field to list everything).

Comment: Does `on_cpu = 1` mean that `rq->curr` is locked? I don't know if I understand it right

Comment: @user14102520 No, `on_cpu = 1` means that the task is currently running (i.e. it's "on the cpu"). It's just a faster way to check than `spin_lock(rq->lock); check rq->curr == p; spin_unlock(rq->lock);`.

Comment: Why is there a situation where `p->on_cpu = 0` but `rq->curr = p`

Comment: @user14102520 who said that? Where did you see it?

Comment: I'm sorry, because I'm doing process migration experiments. When I use `rq->curr` to judge directly, it will cause system abnormalities, but using `p->on_cpu` will not cause problems, so I think `p->on_cpu = 0` and `rq->curr = p` appears

Comment: @user14102520 If you have a specific problem, you will have to post another question about it along with the actual code that you are using. It's impossible to say anything just from your comments.

Comment: Thank you, in this question I mainly want to figure out the meaning of on_cpu, I think I have understood what you mean